# Two pages using the same url depending on login status

Tags: asp.net, routes

What I would like to accomplish is: when user goes to www.mysite.com, then depending on whether he is logged in or not, he would see either login page or his home page. I do not want to redirect to other pages, I want the url to show as www.mysite.com in both cases. Kind of like when you go to facebook.com, it will either show you login page or your wall, all with the same url.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using ASP.NET WebForms (you didn't say) then you can use [Server.Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800%28VS.90%29.aspx) in your home page to render the "login" page instead, if you detect the user is not logged in.

If you are using ASP.NET MVC, then your home page controller can check whether you're logged in or not and render the "login" view instead of whatever the default is.

Otherwise, if you want to use ASP.NET routing, you could do it with a [custom route contraint](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs). So you'd have two routes that match "/" but one has a custom constraint that checks whether the user is logged in or not.

Comment: I do have a WinForms app. I will look into both solutions you offered, Thanks a bunch!